# Hardhat Smart Contracts With NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ethereum, exec, hardhat

I am trying to implement smart contracts with hardhat. From the hardhat documentation, I have seen that we can use the following command to deploy the contract -

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js`

In scripts/deploy.js,

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    const Referral = await ethers.getContractFactory("Referral");

    const referral = await Referral.deploy("0", "1", "2", "3");

    let contractAddress = referral.address;

    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", contractAddress);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

I wanted to deploy the contract on a trigger somewhere in node.js and store the contract address in some storage. But using the above command, I would get the output in the terminal and would have to extract it out using `exec` of nodejs. I wanted to have a function in scripts/deploy.js which I can use to deploy the contracts and can call it from some place in nodejs. Also, it would help in passing some parameters to the function that the `Referral.deploy` would take in 0, 1, 2, 3...

I am very new to web3 ecosystem and trying to see if something like above is achievable.

Comment: *I wanted to deploy the contract on a trigger somewhere in node.js* What do you mean?

Comment: User makes a post request to our node server and then I should deploy the smart contract. So if deployment of smart contract can happen through a function call from where the post request is made, I can store its address accordingly there itself.

Answer (score 0):

To call with param, extract it to a function, for example:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function deployContract(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    const Referral = await ethers.getContractFactory("Referral");
    const referral = await Referral.deploy(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    return referral.address;
}

module.exports = deployContract;
```

Then call it from somewhere else:

```
const deployContract = require("./scripts/deploy");

async function main() {
    const contractAddress = await deployContract("0", "1", "2", "3");
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", contractAddress);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```